# Transfinite Sequence in a Category

Tags: category-theory

**Ordinal Numbers:**

Given a totally ordered set $(X,<)$, and an element $a \in X$, define the section $X_a$ to consist of all elements of $X$ which are less than $a$:
$$X_a := \{x \in X: x < a\}.$$

An **ordinal** is a well-ordered set $(X,<)$ with the property that $X_a = a$ for all $a \in X$. That means every element of $X$ is the set of all its predecessors.

One may often think of ordinal as a small category with a unique morphism from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ if and only if $\alpha < \beta$.

**Transfinite Sequence in a category $\mathcal{C}$:**

Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal (regarded as a small category). An $\alpha$-indexed transfinite sequence ($\alpha$-sequence) in $\mathcal{C}$ is a co-limit preserving diagram $X:\alpha \to \mathcal{C}$, that is
$$X_0 \to X_1 \to \cdots X_\beta \to \cdots$$

---

I am reading a note where it is written:

Since $X$ preserves colimit, for all limit ordinals $\gamma < \lambda$, the induced map
$$\mathrm{colim}_{\beta < \gamma} X_{\beta} \to X_\gamma$$
is an isomorphism.

**My Questions:**

1. Have I written the definition of the transfinite sequence correctly?
2. Why is $\mathrm{colim}_{\beta < \gamma} X_{\beta} \to X_\gamma$ an isomorphism? And to show this isomorphism where do we need the condition that $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ordinal $\beta$ is the colimit of lesser ordinals $\alpha<\beta$ within some ordinal $\gamma\ge \beta$ viewed as a category, if and only if $\beta$ is a limit ordinal. If $\beta=\beta’+1$ is a successor then the colimit of the ordinals less than $\beta$ is instead $\beta’.$ So if a functor out of $\gamma$ preserves all colimits then its action on limit ordinals is fully determined by its action on successors.

Comment: Can you please explain how the action on limit ordinals is fully determined by its action on successors?

Comment: $f(\mathrm{colim}_{\alpha<\beta}f(\alpha))=f(\beta).$